# VS Code is unable to recognize Python module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter, sympy

I'm experiencing an issue with installing and using the 'sympy' module in my Python environment. I created the environment using MiniConda and I'm using VS Code as my code editor. I have already tried installing 'sympy' using both Conda and pip commands, and they both indicate successful installation. However, when I try to import 'sympy' in my Python code, I get a `'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'' error`.

I have double-checked that the module is indeed installed in my environment (everywhere sympy is listed as installed), but it seems that VS Code is unable to recognize it. I have restarted my computer and reactivated my environment, but the issue persists.

Could someone please help me troubleshoot this problem? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!

```
import math

from sympy import*

x= Symbol('x')
l = Symbol('l')
t = Symbol('t')
e = Symbol('e')
```

This is the code I tried to make working.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 3
      1 import math
----> 3 from sympy import*
      5 x= Symbol('x')
      6 l = Symbol('l')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sympy'
```

And this is the Error in detail.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like the Python environment in your VSCode might be *DIFFERENT* than the "global" environment.  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Run `python --version` inside of, and external to, VSCode, 2) Look here: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-install-sympy#modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-sympy-in-python

Comment: Have you set your Python iterpreter in VS Code?

Comment: The environments are the same, the versions are the same. My environment is set and it worked fine in all the others code snippets and imports. If I check my environment in VS Code, sympy is listed in installed packages (Version 1.11.1).

Comment: It still sounds like there might be some "other" Python environment that VSCode is (somehow!) invoking behind your back.  Per JRiggles question: have you (explicitly!) set your Python interpreter in VSCode?  Look here for more details: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments `Tip: In Python, it is best practice to create a workspace-specific environment, for example, by using a local environment.`

Comment: Show us the output of this command `pip show sympy` (specifically the "Location" part), and also show us the output of this short program in vs code `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: Use shortcuts "Ctrl+Shift+P" and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the interpreter which you installed the package in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have discovered the root of the problem!

When you run code in the editor, VSCode simulates a terminal. It types enters into that terminal a line that looks something like this:

> python -u "/path/to/test.py"

Now that python may be version 3, 2, 3.8, 3.10, etc. what you need to do is make sure that the version of python you installed scipy with matches up with the version of python your program is being run in. You can do that by doing the following:

1. Open the VSCode terminal and type this in:

> python -m pip install scipy

2. It will output some stuff while downloading scipy. Here's what it shows for me:

> Collecting scipy
> Downloading scipy-1.10.1-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (35.0 MB)
> ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 35.0/35.0 MB 8.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
> Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.27.0,>=1.19.5 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from scipy) (1.24.3)
> Installing collected packages: scipy
> Successfully installed scipy-1.10.1

3. As you can see on that 4th line of output, it tells me the python version, 3.8. So this means that whenever VSCode runs python, it is running python 3.8. We need to make sure that we are installing scipy with and, in fact, running our code in python 3.8.
4. Press CTRL+Shift+P or CMD+Shift+P depending on your OS, to open the command palette. Search for the 'python interpreter' option. Change your python interpreter to the version mentioned when installing scipy with pip.

That should do it!
Remember to always install using python -m pip install

```py
import scipy

print(scipy)
```

Output:

```py
<module 'scipy' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py'>

# Success!
```

Comment: You're correct that VSCode creates a "virtual environment".  You're also correct that installing whatever package you need (e.g. scipy or sympy) directly into that virtual environment (like you did) can be a viable workaround.  But a *BETTER* solution is to *MANAGE* the virtual environment.  For example, you might want to 1) install externally, but 2) use the external package *INSIDE* VSCode.  Configuring VSCode to explicitly specify which Python to use in your virtual environment allows you to do this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much for all of your suggestions.

I ended up updating Python to 3.11 in both Anaconda and VS Code and created a new environment using Python 3.11. Now it works just fine.